# Mechanism for the synthesis of benzimidazole

Tags: reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, amines

I have thought up a mechanism for the synthesis of benzimidazole from o-phenylenediamine and formic acid. I would like to know if it's correct. I have attached it below.[image]

My rationale for the protonated intermediate is that methyl formate can run without an acidic catalyst (Lewis or Bronsted) and still provide fair yields. Formic acid must be protonating itself for this to work.

Comment: Such protonated carboxylic acid doesn't seem likely intermediate in reaction with amine. I'd rather write proton transfer *after* attack of amine on neutral acid.

Comment: Huh. I guess that makes sense, but then what kicks off water?

Comment: I don't see which part. So, would formic acid protonate the intermediate and then water get kicked off? Explain yourself a little more please.

Comment: Huh, I don't think I get your way of writing mech. Reaction is autocatalysed, you don't have some magical substrate that works out everything. There's surplus of the acid and every possible proton transfer happens all the time. So no, it wasn't OK :(

Comment: Okay. So no self-protonation is necessary?